# Parsing two different html sources and combining the output

Tags: python

I am parsing two different html sources (one spits out "data A,B,C,D, and E" and the other spits out "data F") with two different scripts. I want to combine the output of both of these scripts into a simple csv format.

I am trying to run a 3rd script that imports everything from the other two scripts and prints out the data. This is what I am doing to try and make this happen:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

from script1 import *
from script2 import *

for c in cities :
   c.retrieveTemps()
   print(c.name,c.high0,c.low0,c.high1,c.low1,c.weather0,c.weather1,c.wind0,c.wind1)
```

All the variables are defined in script1 and script2. Script1 finds every variable except for c.wind1. However, when I run the above code, it will only find the data for either script1 OR script2 (depending on which one I import second), not both.

Any ideas on what I can do to get it to print out all the data from both script1 and script2? Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is from script1:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import re
import urllib
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

date = datetime.now()
date1 = date + timedelta(days=1)
date2 = date + timedelta(days=2)


class city :
        def __init__(self, city_name, link) :
                self.name = city_name
                self.url = link
                self.wind1 = 0

    def retrieveTemps(self) :
            filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)

            # get lines from result into array
            lines = filehandle.readlines()

            # (for each) loop through each line in lines
            line_number = 0 # a counter for line number
            for line in lines:
                    line_number = line_number + 1 # increment counter

                    # find string, position otherwise position is -1

                    position2 = line.rfind('<ul class="stats">')

                    #String is found in line

                    if position2 > 0 :
                            self.wind0 = lines[line_number + 1].split('</strong>')[0].split('style="">')[-1]

                            break # done with loop, break out of it

            return ('c.wind0')

            filehandle.close()

m1 = city('Mexico City', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/mexico-city/242560/daily-weather-forecast/242560?day=2')
m3 = city('Veracruz', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/veracruz/236233/daily-weather-forecast/236233?day=2')
m5 = city('Tampico', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/tampico/235985/daily-weather-forecast/235985?day=2')
m7 = city('Nuevo Laredo', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/nuevo-laredo/235983/daily-weather-forecast/235983?day=2')
m9 = city('Monterrey', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/monterrey/244681/daily-weather-forecast/244681?day=2')
m11 = city('S. Luis Potosi', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/san-luis-potosi/245369/daily-weather-forecast/245369?day=2')
m13 = city('Queretaro', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/queretaro/245027/daily-weather-forecast/245027?day=2')
m15 = city('Laz. Cardenas', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/lazaro-cardenas/239054/daily-weather-forecast/239054?day=2')

cities = []
cities.append(m1)
cities.append(m3)
cities.append(m5)
cities.append(m7)
cities.append(m9)
cities.append(m11)
cities.append(m13))
cities.append(m15)
```

Comment: Is `retrieveTemps` a member of `city`? Then you must import and use it as `from script1 import city; c= city(); c.retrieveTemps()`.

Comment: When trying that I get this error:

from kcsm import city; c= city(); c.retrieveTemps()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Importing the namespace of a module is the wrong way. The two Python scripts don't 'spit out' data. Write methods, import them, call them, use the result.

`script1.py`

```
def foo():
    return (1, 2, 3)
```

`script2.py`

```
def bar():
    return ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

`script3.py`

```
from script1 import foo
from script2 import bar

combinedResult = foo() + bar()
```

Comment: This makes sense, though I am not sure I am writing the methods correctly. I have edited the original post to include part of script1.py along with my attempt at writing a method. I tried importing retrieveTemps, but it said it could not import it.

Comment: 'it said it could not import it'. What was the error message?

Comment: File "scriptkcsm.py", line 4, in <module>
    from kcsm2 import retrieveTemps
ImportError: cannot import name retrieveTemps

Comment: I have included all of script1 in the original post now so you can see exactly how it is set up. Does this give you any better of an idea?